# Hijri (islamic) calendar in swift التاريخ الهجري

Tags: ios, swift, hijri

can someone help me please

I'm trying to create an IOS app using Swift language and I need to use Hijri (islamic) calendar

I tried many time but I failed :(

this is my try

```
    let datenow = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max), fromDate: datenow)

    var gregorian = NSCalendar(identifier:NSIslamicCivilCalendar)
    var date = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)

    println(date)
```

and the output is wrong

```
   2576-04-25 09:05:08 +0000
```

We are in year 1434 in hijri not 2576 !

Comment: You told it that we are in the year 2014 hijri, which is a few hundred years in the future, apparently in 2576 AD. Swift is absolutely right; your code is wrong.

Comment: thank you for explainning that to me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mixing up the calendars, dates & components:

```
let datenow = NSDate() 
    // This is a point in time, independent of calendars
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar() 
    // System calendar, likely Gregorian 
let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max), fromDate: datenow) 
    // Gregorian components

println("\(components.year)") // "2014"

var islamic = NSCalendar(identifier:NSIslamicCivilCalendar)! // Changed the variable name 
    // *** Note also NSCalendar(identifier:) now returns now returns an optional ***
var date = islamic.dateFromComponents(components) 
    // so you have asked to initialise the date as AH 2014

println(date) 
    // This is a point in time again, sometime in AH 2014, or AD 2576
```

What you need to do is simply:

```
let datenow = NSDate()
let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier:NSIslamicCivilCalendar)!
let components = islamic.components(NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max), fromDate: datenow)
println("Date in system calendar:\(datenow), in Hijri:\(components.year)-\(components.month)-\(components.day)")
   //"Date in system calendar:2014-09-25 09:53:00 +0000, in Hijri:1435-11-30"
```

To get a formatted string, rather than just the integer components, you need to use `NSDateFormatter`, which will allow you to specify the calendar & date as well as the format. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Update**

To simply transliterate the numerals to [(Eastern) Arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals_(disambiguation)) (as 0...9 are referred to as (Western) Arabic numerals to distinguish them from, say, Roman numerals), as requested, you could use:

```
let sWesternArabic = "\(components.day)-\(components.month)-\(components.year)"
let substituteEasternArabic = ["0":"٠", "1":"١", "2":"٢", "3":"٣", "4":"٤", "5":"٥", "6":"٦", "7":"٧", "8":"٨", "9":"٩"]
var sEasternArabic =  ""
for i in sWesternArabic {
    if let subs = substituteEasternArabic[String(i)] { // String(i) needed as i is a character
        sEasternArabic += subs
    } else {
        sEasternArabic += String(i)
    }
}

println("Western Arabic numerals = \(sWesternArabic), Eastern Arabic numerals = \(sEasternArabic)")
```

Comment: that work great but hot can I print the intger in arabic way like ٠٩/١٠/١٤٣٤

Comment: Printing the Arabic numerals is easy (month names harder) - just get it as a string using 1...9 and then use character substitution to replace 1 with Arabic 1, etc.

Comment: Added transliteration, as requested. Sorry to take all day, I've been working!

Comment: thank you Grimxn and I also find a great way to show arabic numbers
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_SA")
        
        var date:String = "\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.year))-\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.month))-\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.day))"
it will print ١-١١-١٤٣٤

Comment: @AbdulazizNoor - That's really good - way better than my hack. You should post it as an answer, not a comment!

Comment: oh ,Im new here so I didn't know that I can ,but I just did ,thanks for advice :)

Comment: I believe that placing the Arabic integers in the code files may raise a problem where the code file encoding on a specific developer machine/version control could manipulate the Arabic characters, so I think it's better to save them in a localizable strings file

Answer (score 7):

Get Hajri Date:

**Swift :**

```
 let dateFor = DateFormatter()

 let hijriCalendar = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.islamicCivil)
 dateFor.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "ar") // or "en" as you want to show numbers

 dateFor.calendar = hijriCalendar

 dateFor.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
 print(dateFor.string(from: Date()))
```

**Obj-C :**

```
NSCalendar *hijriCalendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil];
NSDateFormatter * lastDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

lastDate.calendar = hijriCalendar2;
[lastDate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString * dateString = [lastDate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification

Answer (score 4):

thank you @Grimxn and I also find a great way to show arabic numbers

```
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_SA")

    var date:String = "\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.year))-\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.month))-\(formatter.stringFromNumber(components.day))"
```

it will print ١-١١-١٤٣٤

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 & 4**

```
let dateNow = DateFormatter()
let islamicCalendar = Calendar.init(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.islamicCivil)
dateNow.calendar = islamicCalendar
dateNow.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "ar_SA") // This is used to show numbers, day and month in arabic letters
dateNow.dateFormat = "EEE dd MMM yyyy"

print("\(dateNow.string(from: Date()))")
```

> find out and place date format from:
>   http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 4):

### Swift 5:

```swift
let hijriCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicCivil)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar")
formatter.calendar = hijriCalendar
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

print(formatter.string(from: Date()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enum HicriTypeFormat: String {
case short = "dd MM yy"
case little = "dd MM yyyy"
case medium = "dd MMM yyyy"
case long = "dd MMMM yyyy"}

func convertToHicri(date: Date, dateFormatT: HicriTypeFormat) -> String {
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = calendar
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormatT.rawValue
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first ?? "en")
return dateFormatter.string(from: date)}
```