# Format NSDate with different calendar identifier?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to print a human-friendly date that's of a different calendar identifier. I am able to get the date, but when I format it, it outputs back to Gregorian (or the user's current calendar I think).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
var calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicCivil)
var flags = NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max)
var components = calendar?.components(flags, fromDate: NSDate())

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle

let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(calendar!.dateFromComponents(components!)!)

println(dateString)
```

This prints: `May 8, 2015`, but I'm trying to get it to print `Rajab 19, 1436`. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you should set the calendar and locale of the NSDateFormatter??

Comment: I am not sure however i have found a good response to similar question hope this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26035658/4056108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line

```
formatter.calendar = calendar
```