# Convert gregorian date to Hijri date

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

The source code comes from:

[Hijri (islamic) calendar in swift التاريخ الهجري](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034840/hijri-islamic-calendar-in-swift)

[How can I convert string date to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

I just put them together but it has some mistake with the output.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

let GregorianDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(Yeartext1.text!)-\(Monthtext1.text!)-\(Daytext1.text!)")

let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier: NSIslamicCalendar)

let components = islamic?.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max), fromDate: GregorianDate!)

resultlable.text = "\(components!.year) - \(components!.month) - \(components!.day)"
```

For example, the user will enter a gregorian date (2015/09/29) and it should show the Hijri year (1436/12/15) but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeartext1 , Monthtext1 and Monthtext1 are UITextField

resultlable is  UILabel

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    let GregorianDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(Daytext1.text!)-\(Monthtext1.text!)-\(Yeartext1.text!)")

    let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierIslamicUmmAlQura)

    let components = islamic?.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max), fromDate: GregorianDate!)

    resultlable.text = "\(components!.year) - \(components!.month) - \(components!.day)"
```

It will take an Gregorian Date 5-10-2015 and it will give you the islamic date 1436 - 12 - 22

*There is a small probability of one day error

you can check this converter 
http://www.islamicfinder.org/Hcal/hdate_next.php

Answer (score 0):

Hijri To Gregorian(this can help someone)

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "ar_SA")

let islamicDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("8-10-1437")

let gregorian = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let components = gregorian?.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max), fromDate: islamicDate!)

print("\(components!.year) - \(components!.month) - \(components!.day)")
```